# Run-time error: 1004 Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range Class

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I am trying to have VBA write a formula in a certain ranges of cells with row values defined by the variable: `Arr(,)`. Because in EXCEL I would Ctrl+Shift+Enter the formula, I am using the `FormulaArray` command. However I am getting: `Run-time error: 1004  Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range Class`.

I have thoroughly checked the string format of the formula by VBA printing is as a string in a cell and comparing it to my normal input in EXCEL. So the formula should be fine. I have checked the length of the `FormulaArray` input and made sure it is well below the 255 character limit. Following a suggestion from online (http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/), I used the `.Replace` command to overcome the word limit.

I have also tried to replace the `With Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(a, j)` command with `With Sheets("Detail analysis").Range(Cells(a,j).Address(0,0))`; however this still gives the FormulaArray error.

Nevertheless, I am still getting the error: `Run-time error: 1004  Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range Class`. **QUESTION EDIT**: When this error is displayed the debugger points towards the line: `.FormulaArray = formulaP1`.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong with the code?

```
' Define variables '
Dim top As Integer
Dim bottom As Integer

Dim a As Integer
Dim sumrows As Double   ' Summation of the Main Loads in a list '
Dim totalsum As Double  ' Generator Loads total '
Dim etotalsum As Double ' Emergency Generator Loads total '
Dim g As Integer
Dim formulaP1 As String
Dim formulaP2 As String
Dim formulaP3 As String
Dim formulaP4 As String
Dim nill As String

nill = Chr(34) & Chr(34)


j = 6

' Loop for the number of "Actual Load" columns required '

Do While Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(9, j).Value = Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(9, 6).Value

totalsum = 0
etotalsum = 0

' Nested Loop for the list ranges identified by the previous code block (i.e. between orange and     blue rows) '

i = 1

Do While Arr(i, 1) <> green ' Green is a previously defined row number '

''''' Identify the Orange (Top) and Blue (bottom) rows of the current list '

    top = Arr(i, 1)
    bottom = Arr(i, 2)


''''' Write formula in the "Actual Load" column between the Arr() rows '
    For a = (top + 1) To (bottom - 1)

    formulaP1 = "=IF(OR($B" & a + 1 & "=" & nill & ",$A" & a & "=" & nill & "),IF(OR($A" & a & "<>" & nill & ",$B" & a & "<>" & "X_X_X()"
    formulaP2 = nill & "),$C" & a & "*$D" & a & "*" & Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(a, j - 1).Address(0, 0) & "," & nill & ")," & "Y_Y_Y()"
    formulaP3 = "SUM(" & Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(a + 1, j).Address(0, 0) & ":INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IFERROR(IF($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & "<>" & nill & "Z_Z_Z()"
    formulaP4 = ",ROW($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & ")-1),#NULL!),1),COLUMN(" & Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(a, j).Address(0, 0) & "),1,1,))))"

         With Sheets("Detail analysis").Cells(a, j)
            .FormulaArray = formulaP1
            .Replace "X_X_X()", formulaP2
            .Replace "Y_Y_Y()", formulaP3
            .Replace "Z_Z_Z()", formulaP4

        End With
    Next a


    Next a

i = i + 1
Loop


j = j + 2

Loop
```

**QUESTION EDIT** Following some further trials I have tried to VBA code some of the conditions in the formula. This divided the formula in two: one statement is `=cell*cell*cell` and so does not require `FormulaArray`. When I ran the code, this commands are executed well.

The second statement is the summation which considers a range of cells to calculate the value. The code is now failing specifically when my conditions call for the `FormulaArray` line. N.B. I checked the number of characters in `formula` and they add up to 250 (less than the 255 limit stated on the MSDN website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104(v=office.15).aspx).

```
ws= Sheets("Detail analysis")

With ws

    formula = "=SUM(" & .Cells(a + 1, j).Address(0, 0) & ":INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IFERROR(IF($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & "<>" & nill & _
                ",ROW($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & ")-1),1E+99),1),COLUMN(" & .Cells(a, j).Address(0, 0) & "),1,1,))))"

End With

For a = (top + 1) To (bottom - 1)

    If ws.Cells(a + 1, 2) = "" Or ws.Cells(a, 1) = "" Then
        If (ws.Cells(a, 1) <> "" Or ws.Cells(a, 2) <> "") And ws.Cells(a, j - 1) <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(a, j).formula = "=$C" & a & "*$D" & a & "*" & ws.Cells(a, j - 1).Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Else
         ws.Cells(a, j).FormulaArray = formula
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: Could it be the embedded quotation marks in the formula string. Perhaps try doubling these up or using Chr(34) to distinguish them from closing the string?

Comment: I have used the `nill= Char(34) & Char(34)` command to call the `""`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `#NULL!` that you had to `1E+99` so it would never be `SMALL`. Not sure where `#NULL!` comes from but it isn't an accepted Excel error code. I also changed the method of assembling the array formula, choosing to assemble it as a string in the cell and only make it an array formula *after* the replacements were made and the formula was fully formed. With no data to test on and some vars made up (the values were missing in the sample), I came up with this.

```
' Write formula in the "Actual Load" column between the Arr() rows '
For a = (top + 1) To (bottom - 1)
     With Sheets("Detail analysis")
        formulaP1 = "'=IF(OR($B" & a + 1 & "=" & nill & ",$A" & a & "=" & nill & "),IF(OR($A" & a & "<>" & nill & ",$B" & a & "<>" & "X_X_X()"
        formulaP2 = nill & "),$C" & a & "*$D" & a & "*" & .Cells(a, j - 1).Address(0, 0) & "," & nill & ")," & "Y_Y_Y()"
        formulaP3 = "SUM(" & .Cells(a + 1, j).Address(0, 0) & ":INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IFERROR(IF($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & "<>" & nill & "Z_Z_Z()"
        formulaP4 = ",ROW($A" & a + 2 & ":$A$" & bottom & ")-1),1E99),1),COLUMN(" & .Cells(a, j).Address(0, 0) & "),1,1,))))"

        With .Cells(a, j)
            .Value = formulaP1
            .Replace What:="X_X_X()", Replacement:=formulaP2, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="Y_Y_Y()", Replacement:=formulaP3, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="Z_Z_Z()", Replacement:=formulaP4, lookat:=xlPart
            .FormulaArray = .Value
        End With
    End With
Next a
```

*Addendunm:* the `.Replace` functionality would have defaulted to what was last used. If this was `xlWhole` then the `.Replace` and the subsequent `.FormulaArray` assignment would again fail. I've modified to specify the `, lookat:=xlPart` parameter.

Comment: I tried replacing the `#NULL!` with the very `1E99` to make sure that there it doesn't go to `SMALL` as you suggested. However, I don't think this was the issue.

Comment: I also tried writing the formula in the cell in the way you suggested. The error I am being presented with now at the line `.Value=formulaP1` is "Run-time error '1004'   Application-defined or object-defined error". In my experience this normally has to do with the focus of the command but I cannot find any fault in it...

I also tried to change it to `.Formula= formulaP1` but it didn't resolve the problem.

This is now not letting me get to the line `FormulaArray=.Value` so I can investigate if the solution works.

Comment: @Galju - Did you preface the string in `formulaP1 = "'=IF(OR(...` with a single quote as I did to force a text value into the cell? If not, my apologies... that was kinda hidden and probably should have been mentioned.

Comment: It always comes down to something that small! No need to apologize, I am the one who missed that. The code runs smoothly now in the way you suggested. Thank you very much for you help.